# Artinian rings that are not Artin algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

An Artin algebra $A$ is an algebra over a commutative Artinian ring $R$ which is finitely generated over $R$, e.g. finite dimensional algebra over a field. Clearly, any Artin algebra is left and right Artinian.

What are examples of left and right Artinian rings that not Artin algebras?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the first Weyl field $D_1(k)$ over a field $k$, that is, the skew-field of quotients of the first Weyl algebra $A_1(k)$ over $k$. As it is a division ring, it is of course left and right artinian. On the other hand, the center of $D_1(k)$ is $k$, so $D(k)$ is not finitely generated  as a module over any central subring — if $k=\mathbb  C$ for example, $D_1$ has uncountable dimension over $k$.

The first example in history of such a thing is as follows: let $\def\QQ{\mathbb{Q}}\QQ(t)$ be the field of rational functions with rational coefficients, let $\sigma:\QQ(t)\to\QQ(t)$ be the field automorphism such that $\sigma(t)=2t$, consider the ring $\QQ(t)[[X]]$ of power series with coefficients in $\QQ(t)$ with multiplication twisted so that $Xf=\sigma(f)X$ for all $f\in\QQ(t)$ (this can be viewed as a power-series version of the Ore extension of $\QQ(t)$ by $\sigma$) One can localize this ring by inverting $X$, and one gets a ring of Laurent series $D$ with coefficients in $\QQ(t)$ in the variable $X$ with the same commutation relation. The center of $D$ is $\QQ$, so $D$ is not finitely generated over its center. This example is due to Hilbert, if I recall correctly.

Comment: There is a close connection between the two examples: there is a well-known embedding of the first Weyl field into a skew field of Laurent power series. This is, in fact, the way one usually does anything useful with $D_1(k)$.

Comment: As usual, one should look in Lam's book on noncommuattive rings for this sort of information, I am sure he gives the Hilbert example there!

Comment: One can get examples of artinian non-Artin non-division rings in silly ways: consider $D_1(k)[T]/(T^2)$, say.

Answer (score 1):

An example of a different flavour than the Weyl field, comes from the fact that even if $R$ is both left and right Artininan, the center of $R$ need not be. One such example is given in

*Jensen, Christian U.; Jøndrup, Søren.* [**Centres and Fixed-Point Rings of Artinian Rings**](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01214261.pdf) Math. Z. 130 (1973), 189--197. MR0318222

I'll rewrite it here for convenience:
Let $F$ be a field and $I$ be an infinite set. Let $K$ be the field of fractions of $F[t_i^{1/2^j} |i\in I, j \in \mathbb N]$. Define an $F$-algebra automorphism of $K$ by squaring the variables: $\sigma(t_i^{1/2^j}) = t_i^{1/2^{j-1}}$.

Define $A$ to be the ring $K + Kx + Ky$, where $xk = \sigma(k)x$ and $yk=ky$ for $k \in K$, and $x^2 = y^2 = xy = yx = 0$. then the center of $A$ is $F+Ky$ which is not artinian.